# Remove directory from URL. Web.Config URLRewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, web-config, vps

I am working on a little web project to expand my knowledge in web development.
I currently do not have a domain so am working by Server IPs.
This is my current Web.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

      <rewrite>
        <rules>

          <rule name="Hide .html ext">
            <match ignoreCase="true" url="^(.*)"/>
                      <conditions>
                          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile"/>
                      </conditions>
                      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html"/>
                  </rule>

                  <rule name="Redirecting .html ext" stopProcessing="true">
                      <match url="^(.*).html"/>
                      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                          <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).html"/>
                      </conditions>
                      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
                  </rule>


              </rules>
          </rewrite>

        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="landing.html" />
                <add value="landing.asp" />
                <add value="landing.htm" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="rules-Integrated" path="*.rules" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="rules-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.rules" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="rules-64-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.rules" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="xoml-Integrated" path="*.xoml" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="xoml-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.xoml" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="xoml-64-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.xoml" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="svc-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="svc-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="svc-Integrated" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="WebDAV" path="*" verb="PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,MKCOL,PUT,COPY,DELETE,MOVE,LOCK,UNLOCK" type="" modules="WebDAVModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="ASPClassic" path="*.asp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="SecurityCertificate" path="*.cer" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="ISAPI-dll" path="*.dll" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="TraceHandler-Integrated" path="trace.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="WebAdminHandler-Integrated" path="WebAdmin.axd" verb="GET,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.WebAdminHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="AssemblyResourceLoader-Integrated" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory, System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-Integrated" path="*.rem" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandlerFactory, System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-soap-Integrated" path="*.soap" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandlerFactory, System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="AXD-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.rem" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-soap-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.soap" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="AXD-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.rem" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-soap-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.soap" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="CGI-exe" path="*.exe" verb="*" type="" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="SSINC-stm" path="*.stm" verb="GET,POST" type="" modules="ServerSideIncludeModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="SSINC-shtm" path="*.shtm" verb="GET,POST" type="" modules="ServerSideIncludeModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="SSINC-shtml" path="*.shtml" verb="GET,POST" type="" modules="ServerSideIncludeModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="TRACEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="TRACE" type="" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" type="" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="Wildcard Script Map" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Everything is in order with it. It works how I need it to work.
But i would like to add a rule which removes /pages/ from the URL.
For example, (server_IP)/pages/about needs to be (server_IP)/about.
I have already removed the file extensions in the URL so I don't need that.
I just want the directory to be removed from the URL